# How to use assets from StreamingAssets Folder in Unity Editor (assets such as fonts)?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am using a Font in Unity Editor as well as Android Plugin library, so I want to use the same font asset or file for both Unity Editor as well as Android Plugin Library.

The problem is that, Font placed in **StreamingAssets** folder gets copied to Android APK and is available in Android Plugin Library (Java code). But the font is not available in Unity Editor while editing scenes.

Same way when I place the Font asset or file in **Resources** folder or in any other folder in **Assets** folder, the font is available in Unity Editor, but not copied in Android APK while building. Hence not available in Android Plugin Library.

I want to use same file in both Unity Editor and Android Plugin as it will increase apk size and there is no need for redundant files. Is there any way to make it work?

Please note that I want it to work while editing scenes as well as at runtime.

Comment: Can't you just put it in a normal folder that is not `Resources` nor `StreamingAssets` nor any other [Special Folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) .. `but not copied in Android APK while building` why should it not? As soon as it is anywhere referenced it would definitely be included in a build just as any scene, prefab, texture and other assets..

Comment: @derHugo, if the font is placed in any other folder in **Assets** folder, then how can I access it in Android Plugin Library's Java code. I am accessing by code `Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mainActivity.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/segoeuisl.ttf");`

Comment: @derHugo, waiting for your reply. How can I access font placed inside any folder in Unity's **Assets** folder from Android Plugin's Java Code. This is my Java code `Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mainActivity.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/segoeuisl.ttf");`.

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin If you put fonts in StreamingAssets folder, their paths will be `Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/fonts/segoeuisl.ttf"` in Unity Editor.